# Way to get ALL cookies created in Awesomium? (including Http)

Tags: c#

I'm using the Awesomium .NET API to log in to http://www.habbo.com using the username and password provided by the user in a text box. The issue I have is that to send further requests (eg. navigate to a room - Habbo is an online game) via Http I need to send the same cookies, otherwise it doesn't work.

I'm trying to send the navigate request using this code:

```
using (WebClient WC = new WebClient())
            {
                WC.Headers["X-App-Key"] = Token;
                WC.DownloadString(new Uri(string.Format("http://www.habbo.com/components/roomNavigation?targetId={0}&roomType=private&move=true", roomID)));
            }
```

I need to attach the Http cookies to WC in order for it to be successful. I'm logging in to http://www.habbo.com using this code:

```
public int Timer = 0;
        public void AttemptLogin_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Timer++;
            if (Timer == 1)
            {
                webControl1.Source = new Uri("http://www.habbo.com/client");
            }
            if (Timer == 3)
            {
                webControl1.Source = new Uri(string.Format("https://www.habbo.com/account/submit?credentials.username={0}&credentials.password={1}", username2, password2));
            }
            if(Timer == 6)
            {
                webControl1.Source = new Uri("http://www.habbo.com/client");
            }
        }
```

I know I can get some of the cookies using

```
webControl1.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.cookie;");
```

but this doesn't get the Http ones I need also. The cookies are unique to each session, so as far as I'm aware using HttpWebRequest to get them would result in different Http cookies to the ones I need (and therefore log me out if I tried sending them instead, as it would indicate I had two sessions logged in).

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I think you mean http _headers_. Http itself does not use cookies, it just provides a means to transport them.

Comment: httponly cookies lie phpsessid